# Allow more than content-type: application/json in gorilla

Tags: go

Using the excellent Gorilla mux I have special handler for API requests using application/json as content-type:

```
apiRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api").Headers("Content-Type", "application/json").Subrouter()
```

However, some users like to provide more than just that string, i.e.  application/json; charset=UTF-8. When this header value is set, the handler returns a 404.

What's the best way to handle this by allowing json and any charset specs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers that use regex match any charset or worse even something like `application/jsonfooo`. If you want be more strict, you can use a matcher function:

```
func matchJSON(r *http.Request, rm *mux.RouteMatch) bool {
    ctHdr := r.Header.Get("Content-Type")
    contentType, params, err := mime.ParseMediaType(ctHdr)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    charset := params["charset"]
    return contentType == "application/json" && (charset == "" || strings.EqualFold(charset, "UTF-8"))
}
```

Then, use it like:

```
router.PathPrefix("/api").MatcherFunc(matchJSON)
```

Comment: Updated to be the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I upvoted for the hint to use the MatcherFunc ... but semantically Content-Type and Accept mean different things. If you want to route based on the requested _response type_ then you should use the _accept_ header. And to use that, you need to handle content type negotiation... The best example I know of for this is NegotiateContentType from "github.com/golang/gddo/httputil" (recently archived)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good use case for HeadersRegexp.

From [the Go Doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux):

Regex support also exists for matching Headers within a route. For example, we could do:

`r.HeadersRegexp("Content-Type", "application/(text|json)")`

...and the route will match both requests with a Content-Type of `application/json` as well as `application/text`

Comment: I want to match on application/json for sure, but also allow charset=UTF-8. This may work. If you can add that to your answer above, I can mark it as accepted... unless there is a someone else with a better idea.
<code>
apiRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api").HeadersRegexp("Content-Type", fmt.Sprintf("%s.*", MIMEApplicationJSON)).Subrouter()
</code>

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
apiRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api").HeadersRegexp("Content-Type", fmt.Sprintf("%s.*", MIMEApplicationJSON)).Subrouter()
```

Remember, you may apply routing at the actual end point rather than at the root level. For GET requests there would be no need to specify Content-Type, but for POST, you should check for one.